# Why doesn't the Linux kernel use modulo for long?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel

Both in [modulo function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/math64.h#L103) and in [timespec normalization](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time.c#L357) the kernel code computes modulo by a loop, and prevents the compiler from optimizing the loop to a modulo operator.

Why is that needed?

I expect that if this optimization is not good the compiler will simply not do that. Except, there might be architectures where this optimization is faster. Why is this code needed for all architectures?

Answer (score 2):

It is done this way for cases where the programmer *knows* that the dividend is expected to only be a little larger than the divisor (so the iteration version will only loop once or twice).  The compiler can't be expected to figure this out.  This is explained by this comment in [`div64.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9/lib/div64.c):

```
/*
 * Iterative div/mod for use when dividend is not expected to be much
 * bigger than divisor.
 */
```

The modulo function you've pointed to is `iter_div_u64_rem()`, explicitly used when this is wanted; for the regular modulo version, there is `div_u64_rem()`.

Comment: Furthermore, on most 32-bit architectures, using the `%` operator on a 64-bit value requires helper functions from the C runtime library that are not available in the kernel.

Comment: @caf why does the timespec normalization function use it then? Timespec are huge, and can be easily divided by tiny amounts.

Comment: @Chi-Lan: The timespec normalisation always divides the nanoseconds value by a fixed value, 1000000000.  A de-normalised timespec is generally created by subtracting one timespec from another or adding two timespecs together.  This will leave the nanoseconds member within 1 second of being in the correct range, so the division/modulo loop will likely only loop once.